# Display decoded JSON Dictionary values in SwiftUI Text() without using a List

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I've never used SwiftUI before, but I've managed to get a functioning app for our Help Desk so bear with me. On the primary Content View, I have successfully fetched all tickets from a link with JSON and displayed that limited data in a list of all tickets. When you click the ticket, it opens a second view with just that Ticket's limited info passed from the Primary View and some action buttons. In this second view, I've created a call that gets all details of that specific ticket (JSON Dictionary), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to display that data even though I can print it in the console.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TicketDetails: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var type: String
    var location: Location
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let locationName: String
}

class FetchTick {
    func getTicket(completion: @escaping (TicketDetails) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "URLWITHSENSITIVEINFOREMOVEDFORDEMO") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            let ticket = try! JSONDecoder().decode(TicketDetails.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(ticket)
            }
            print(ticket)
        }
        .resume()
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var ticketStatusAction = TicketStatusAction()
    @State var ticket: [TicketDetails] = []
    @State private var showingOpenAlert = false
    @State private var showingDepotAlert = false
    @State private var showingCloseAlert = false

    // These are passed in from the Primary View and display fine below
    var id: Int
    var type: String
    var displayClient: String
    var shortDetail: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text("\(id)")
                .onAppear {
                    FetchTick().getTicket { (ticketDetails) in
                        self.ticket = self.ticket
                    }}
                .padding()
            
            Text("\(displayClient)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size:20))
                .padding()

            Divider()
            Text("\(shortDetail)")
                .padding()
            HStack() {
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingOpenAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Set to Open")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(size:11))
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingOpenAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want change \(displayClient)'s ticket to Open?"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Set Open"))
                            {
                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, desiredStatus: 1)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDepotAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Depot Ticket")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(size:11))
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingDepotAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to depot \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Depot"))
                            {
                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, desiredStatus: 6)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingCloseAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Close Ticket")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(size:11))
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingCloseAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to close \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Close"))
                            {
                            self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, desiredStatus: 3)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this and access this view (See Screenshot), it successfully prints

```
TicketDetails(id: 2282, type: "Ticket", location: WHD.Location(locationName: "DES"))
```

So I know that I'm actually getting the correct data.

[image]

How do I put that data, say for example the ticket locationName, into a Text() field?

Comment: `self.ticket = self.ticket`?

Comment: How does this help? If I change this in the code I get the error "Cannot assign value of type '[TicketDetails]?' to type '[TicketDetails]'" Also, this would only effect the code displayed in the console.

Comment: I was asking why do you have `self.ticket = self.ticket` in your code? This seems to be the issue

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I think I ended up there because XCode was throwing errors and this was the suggestion it gave me and it produced the data I needed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from code here is how it could be (not tested, due to not testable provided snapshot)

```
Text("\(id)")
    .onAppear {
        FetchTick().getTicket { (ticketDetails) in
            self.ticket = [ticketDetails]   // ticket declared as [TicketDetails]
        }}
    .padding()
         
if !ticket.isEmpty {
   Text(self.ticket.first?.location.locationName ?? "") 
}
```